# How to sort Core Data array based on Date Entered

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have a small Core Data Model which stores an array of Strings (search history).

When fetching the Data I'd like to sort by the time created.  I currently just have one property in my model called `searchHistory` is there a way I can use the following code `(key:` to sort the data or will I need to add a time saved to the model?

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "", ascending: true)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a second attribute declared as non-optional `Date` for example `dateCreated`. In the `NSManagedObject` subclass override `awakeFromInsert` to assign the current date when the record is created.

```
override func awakeFromInsert() {
    super.awakeFromInsert()
    dateCreated = Date()
}
```

Then you can sort

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateCreated", ascending: true)]
```

in `ascending` order means the oldest entry comes first.