# Is there a way to keep the sorting in core data in the time order the objects are added?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, core-data

If I just add mocked `data` to `coreData` like this:

```
func mockData() {´
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "LocalDoorCoreDataObject", in: context)

    for i in 1...3 {
        var myEntity = MyCoreDataObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        myEntity.dName = "MOCKED NAME \(i)"
        }
    }
```

But when I `fetch` the `data` it's not ordered 1, 2, 3, but is rather listed randomly. Is there a way to `store` and `fetch` the `data` exactly in the order you `store` it to the `coreData`? This is important since I want to be able to rearrange the order of the `cells` by dragging them to a different place, then storing the changes to `coreDatabase`.

Comment: Add a `Date` attribute and set it on insert with the current date.

Comment: Or add a sort descriptor on dName if it is just for testing

Comment: Do you think you guys could elaborate a bit? A bit new to core data :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the `NSManagedObject` subclass add an attribute (of course also in the model)

   ```
   @NSManaged var itemAdded : Date
   ```
2. Override `awakeFromInsert`

   ```
   override func awakeFromInsert() {
       super.awakeFromInsert()
       itemAdded = Date()
   }
   ```

Now you can sort by `itemAdded`

Comment: As you wrote here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57841755/1187415 :)