# How do I sort core data objects by date modified and list it in the right order in a tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, uitableview, rx-swift

I have been struggling a long time with moving `cells` in a `tableView` and getting them in the correct order. I want to be able to drag the `cells` from one place to another using `rx.itemMoved`. The order also has to persist over time so I save it to `coreData` and then `sort` it according to `Date` as suggested here:

[Is there a way to keep the sorting in core data in the time order the objects are added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955435/is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-sorting-in-core-data-in-the-time-order-the-objects-ar/61957498#61957498)

But I just can't seem to get it right with the sorting. I don't think I fully understand how to sort it based on date.

I mock data like this:

```
func mockData() {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "LocalDoorCoreDataObject", in: context)
    var data: [LocalDoorCoreDataObject] = []
    for i in 1...3 {
        let myEntity = LocalDoorCoreDataObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        myEntity.dCount = Int16(i)
        myEntity.dName = "M \(i)"
        data.append(myEntity)
    }
    viewModel.mockedRelay.accept(data.compactMap{ RemoteTableViewCellViewModel(localDoor: $0)})
}
```

And this triggers the `bind` on my `tableView`:

```
func setBindings() {
    viewModel.mockedRelay.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: RemoteTableViewCell.identifier, cellType: RemoteTableViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
        cell.viewModel = data
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Now when I drag a `cell` from one place to another:

```
tableView.rx.itemMoved.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] indexPaths in
    let delete = self?.viewModel.mockedRelay.value[indexPaths.sourceIndex.row]
    self?.deleteOne(position: indexPaths.sourceIndex.row) //deletes object in core data 

    self?.setData2(data: delete!) //add the moved object to cd. A new date is added to it
    self?.completionRelay?.accept("DATA SAVED") //Saves data for core data
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

When I add a new object to `coreData` a new date is set:

```
extension LocalDoorCoreDataObject {
    public override func awakeFromInsert() {
        setPrimitiveValue(Date(), forKey: "dModifiedDate")
    }
}
```

Now, the thing I don't get is how `date` should help me sort it in the way I left it when leaving the `view`. If I have three `cells` and move one of them, the moved `cell` gets a higher `date` and the other two have lower `dates`. What if I left the moved `cell` in the middle? Then how would its higher date help me at all? Here's the `fetch` code:

```
func fetchMyData2() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<LocalDoorCoreDataObject>(entityName: "LocalDoorCoreDataObject")
        do {
            Observable.of(try context?.fetch(request))
                .map { item in
                    item?.sorted(by: {(item1, item2) -> Bool in
                        let ordered = item1.dModifiedDate?.compare(item2.dModifiedDate!) == .orderedAscending
                        return ordered
                    })
                }
                .subscribe(onNext: { value in
                    self.viewModel.mockedRelay.accept(value!.compactMap {
                        return RemoteTableViewCellViewModel(localDoor: $0)})
                })
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        } catch {
            print("error", error.localizedDescription) }
    }
```

Let me know if there is something I haven't explained clearly enough or if there is additional code I need to post. I'm aware that a lot of this is bad code, but I really just want to get it to work for now.

Comment: To me it looks like Date is not the right solution here, if you want to store a user defined sort order then you need an Int property to hold the sort order (that is the row number) and update it for all items affected when a row is moved.

Comment: I disagree somewhat with @JoakimDanielson. The objects shouldn't have to be modified at all when the sort order is changed. That should be stored in a separate table (Observable). Each object should have an invariant unique ID and there should be an `Observable<[Object.ID]>` that determines order of the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by doing this:

```
var items = self.mockedRelay.value
let item = items.remove(at: indexPaths.sourceIndex.row)
items.insert(item, at: indexPaths.destinationIndex.row)
```

Now that the `array` is sorted the way I want it I can add index values to it:

```
for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
    item.localDoor.dRow = Int16(index)
}
```

And that's it! New index values for all `objects` every time the `cells` are moved.